# Can not access windows share folder on local host using dns record

Tags: windows, dns, shared-folders

I have a shared folder on my server `Terminal03`, the folder is on `D:temp`, the shared path is `\\Terminal03\temp` and there is a dns record `apps` which points to `Terminal03`.
The folder is accessible for all domain users, either by `\\Terminal03\temp` or `\\apps\temp`. I tested it with some users on different terminals.
If I open `\\Terminal03\temp` or `\\localhot\temp` on the server itself it works too.
If again on the server itself I try `\\apps\temp` it doesn't, it asks the credentials and even if the right one are submitted, it says that they are wrong. Also using system administrator accounts.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\\Terminal03\temp` or `\\localhost\temp` on the server itself works
because it uses the loopback network interface.
The connection never goes out of the server, meaning being handled inside
the server, which is designed to work well.

Using `\\apps\temp` is translated to something like `\\192.168.1.1\temp`,
which requires going to the router and back to the server.
The loop required for getting an answer back looks like:
*server-router-server-router-server*.

Most consumer-grade routers are not capable of supporting such connections,
and your router must be one of those.